# Selecting class + whatever ending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having several elements that start with the same prefix in their IDs. For example #myid_3689, #myid_2348 and so forth.

How can I with JavaScript select all IDs that contains the same word or starts the same? 
I mean something like jQuery('#myid(*)')

I have found several options but none work on my JavaScript. I cannot use $ and jQuery-specific operators. Sorry, I'm  a newbie.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='myid']")`

Comment: `$("[id^='myid']")`